# MongoDb is not picking index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

After deleting and recreating the compound index: **createdBy_1_status_1_createdAt_-1**

The query is not picking the existing index for the below query:

```
{ createdBy: ObjectId('620dde50a1af74407c2827b5'), status: "Active", createdAt: { $gte: new Date('2022-11-21T07:45:36.000+00:00'), $lte: new Date('2023-11-21T07:45:36.000+00:00')}}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Why do you think so? Are you not happy with 4ms execution time?

Comment: Yeah there's too little information here to assist. It would be great to have the output of `.explain()` for the query _and_ `.getIndexes()` from the same shell session. Probably running the query and creating the index in different namespaces/environments

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a bug in mango Compass **Version 1.38.0**
When I run this on **version 1.35.0**,
It is picking indexing:

[image]

Comment: While that _could_ be the case, certainly software does have bugs all the time, I doubt it's the explanation of what you observed in this particular case. You saw correct index usage with the old version of Compass prior to recreating the index right? Compass is just going to report stats from the database, so where did it get `COLLSCAN` and those metrics from? Moreover, the two screenshots show different number of documents being returned. Docs returned is _not_ something that index changes, so this suggests the two screenshots were pointing to different namespaces/environments

Comment: All that said, it is generally advisable to use the latest version of a program so upgrading Compass is probably a good step to take anyway. Just be sure that it is connected to the right collection when working with it to avoid a similar problem in the future